# Parse [PFUser currentUser] Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I am using Xcode and until today haven't realised any problems. My AppDelegate employs the following code to determine where a user should be directed to the main window or to the login screen.

```
// determine the initial view controller here and instantiate it
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    if (!currentUser) {
        // Show Login / Sign Up Window
        viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signUpOrRegister"];
    } else {
        // User Logged In Already
        viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootVC"];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And then the following code to login. The login is registered in the Log.

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:[_loginUsernameField.text lowercaseString]
                                 password:_loginPasswordField.text
                                    block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                        if (user) {
                                            // Do stuff after successful login.
                                            [self displayMessageToUser:@"Welcome Back"];
                                            NSLog(@"Successful: Login: %@", user.objectId);
                                            [self segueToWindowOfChoice];
                                        } else {
                                            // The login failed. Check error to see why.
...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

D :-)

Comment: You haven't said what isn't working. Is it that it's just returning nil? Are you sure that's not correct?

Comment: It was returning nil (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it just by updating the Parse Framework which has strangely resolved the issue? Might be useful for people in this situation in the future